# Previously working (in 1.4.7) Apache Wicket 6 DataView not updating when data source SortableDataProvider is updated from a ModalWindow

Tags: ajax, apache, wicket

As the title says, I am trying to update a web app to a more recent Apache Wicket version. The problem is very like this one here, albeit the link is very old (and an ancient version of Wicket, which is not what I'm using)

http://users.wicket.apache.narkive.com/tG6XOAUM/refresh-page-after-form-submit-within-modalwindow

So what I do is:
- display a DataView in a regular page, populated using a SortableDataProvider 
- create a panel inside a ModalWindow to make some data changes;
- on onSubmit (using an AjaxFallbackButton) inside this panel, insert a new item into the same SortableDataProvider which I use to populate my DataView
- I then call "target.add(wmc)" on the WebMarkupContainer surrounding my DataView
- my DataView.populateItem registers the change when I add trace code, but the change is not actually displayed ie the screen is apparently not being refreshed.

If I do the same thing from an AjaxFallbackButton.onSubmit() NOT inside a ModalWindow, but in the same WebPage as my DataView, then all is well and I see the change on the page immediately.

I started to upgrade to Wicket 8 but there is so much else to change that I'd rather not do this right now.

I can post code if needs be but I wondered if anyone had come across this problem. As I say, fine in Wicket 1.4.7. Next step would be to create a mini-app to demonstrate this, I guess, which might well lead me to a solution anyway but hoping for some good input from that Wicket community out there ;-)

Comment: Hard to tell without any code :/

Comment: Yeah, I know, it's the obvious thing to do but but it means disentangling a test case. Will do today.

Comment: Ok, code posted at www.bananasoft.net/wicket6ajaxrefreshwithdataviewview.zip. Two cases; clicking a button from the same page to add a line works, but doing same from ModalWindow does not. In the latter case the call doesn't seem actually to update the DataProvider even though I'm calling the same method on the same object to add that line.

Comment: Actually - having debugged further, the dataview.populateItem does appear to get the new item but the screen redraw isn't happening and next time I try it, the new item isn't part of the data set of the DataProvider.

Answer (score 0):

You're holding a reference from one page to another:

```
public class TestBugInsertItemPage extends WebPage {

    private TestBugPage parent;
```

This not allowed in Wicket, and I wonder how this has worked in 1.4.

Your trying to update components from another window, that cannot work:

```
    @Override
    protected void onSubmit(AjaxRequestTarget target, Form<?> form) {
        TestBugInsertItemPage.this.parent.dp.addLine();
        target.add(TestBugInsertItemPage.this.parent.wmc);
        TestBugInsertItemPage.this.parent.modal.close(target);
    }
```

An AjaxRequestTarget is valid for a single request for a single page only.

You should use a ModelWindow with a panel instead.

**Update for your second example:**

Passing a panel to a different page won't make a difference. Wicket serializes pages to disk, thus you cannot share any state between them.

You should use a modal dialog *with* a panel instead:

```
TestBugPage.this.modal.setContent(TestBugPage.this.myPanel);
```

Now TestBugPage and your panel reside in the same component hierarchy, they communicate with each other and both can be updated on the same Ajax request.

Comment: Really - it can't work? It did in Wicket 1.4.7. Maybe that was by accident but it did.

Tried the panel approach, no different (see 
www.bananasoft.net/wicket6ajaxrefreshwithdataviewview2.zip) but not surprising if what you say is true. Thanks.